# Is there a tool to monitor synchronisation objects (mutex, events, semaphores) in Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, synchronization

In Windows, is there a tool to monitor the status of process synchronisation objects? ie.

- event/mutex : signaled or not signaled
- semaphore : count

Better yet, to log which thread did what, eg. "thread #5421 Signal Event - testevt"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Memory Validator](http://www.memoryvalidator.com/cpp/memory/memval_object.html)

[Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)

[Handle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx)  usage: handle -s    ==>    `Print count of each type of handle open.`

**[EDIT]**:

**How to monitor the status of process synchronization objects using Process Explorer.**

Open Process Explorer

- Click on your exe in the process section (for ex: MyApp.exe)
- Click `Show Lower Pane` (or press `Ctrl+L`). This will show all synchronization objects. (for ex: myEvent)
- Right click on synchronization
  object (for ex: myEvent) and click
  Properties... in context menu.
- This brings the details of the synchronization object.
  In the `Details` tab, you can see

  `Event Info` (if synch object is event): Gives information about the
  state (whether the synchronization object is signaled)

  `Semaphore info` (if synch object is semaphore):
  Provides the count of the semaphore.

Comment: +1 for Process Explorer - this is what I'd used to explore NT objects

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Now I really know Process Explorer meets my needs.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Intel's ThreadChecker and Parallel Studio. Most of their tools sit on top of Visual Studio.

http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-vtune/

http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-thread-checker/

http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-vtune/

Answer (score 1):

[Thread Validator](http://www.softwareverify.com/cpp/thread/index.html) does what you are describing.

Monitor threads, status of locks, individual thread objects. Much faster than Intel's Thread Checker, but different level of detail.

Answer (score 0):

Windbg can be helpful but you have to learn how to use it.